# How to change src of <embed> tag in a content editor?

Tags: 2010, content-editor-web-part

I have inserted the below code to display my file in content editor web part.

```
   <object><embed src="somfile" height="850" width="850" 

   type="application/pdf"></embed></object>
```

The content editor is on a separate page. When I go to the page containing content editor, I am also passing a query string with the location of file in the library. Now I want to replace the src in `<embed>`  so that the specified file is opened in the content editor. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through javascript. If you pass the querystring in the URL, you can fetch it with javascript and update the `embed` element.

[How to get querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript). Code from answer, below:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

So in your Content Editor Web Part, you place the following javascript above/below (whichever) your `embed` element.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    var qsValue = getParameterByName("query string name here");
    if (qsValue)
    {
        var embed = document.getElementById("ExampleEmbed");
        embed.src = qsValue;
    }
</script>

<object><embed id="ExampleEmbed" src="somfile" height="850" width="850" 
   type="application/pdf"></embed></object>
```

Comment: It is not able to change the src.  I entered this url "http://localhost/ProjDemo/viewTheDoc.aspx?pdf=http://localhost/ProjDemo/File1.pdf"

Comment: @ABeginner Perhaps this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646413/how-to-change-the-value-of-embed-src-with-javascript

Comment: It is still not able to update the src

Comment: I don't know why it is not able to copy "ExampleEmbed" into embed variable. When I debugged the above code it is showing me null in "embed"